# How to traverse a data frame in diagonal fashion given it's start point?

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, traversal

My dataframe looks something like this :

```
               a              b         c           d             e          f        g
4/8/2019    1075808.87  1644784.21  1685870.31  1731148.98  1584775.48  1034996.08  1275391.36
4/1/2019    1294067.7   1685870.31  1731148.98  1584775.48  1034996.08  1275391.36  1413338.42
3/25/2019   1029140.58  1731148.98  1592688.28  1034996.08  nan         1413338.42  1199106.46
3/18/2019   1198887.07  1592688.28  nan         1275391.36  1413338.42  1219381.27  292696.31
3/11/2019   1114531.11  1386283.18  1275391.36  1415951.66  1403053.11  457301.57    nan
```

The number of rows and columns are not fixed and might change

#### Given a date and column name I want to traverse diagonally in upward fashion

For example if **3/18/2019 , d** is the input  :

```
The code / function should return :

3/25/2019 , e , nan
4/1/2019 ,  f , 1275391.36
4/8/2019 ,  g , 1275391.36
```

[image]

similarly if **4/1/2019 , e** is the input :

#### out:

```
4/8/2019 ,f , 1034996.08
```

I am not sure how to traverse using locations

Answer (score 0):

I guess you´re setting two indexes, one for the columns and one for the rows. Let´s say row index is 'i' and column index is 'j'.

Diagonally(to the right) and in upward fashion means a direction for each index:

For the row index (i) it means that it's decreasing (it´s going in upward fashion) and for the column index (j) it means that it´s increasing (it´s going diagonally to the right).

You can use 2 for loops (one inside the other) to navigate the matrix in the way you want it to.

For example:

```
for i in range(row_input - 1, -1, -1):
     for j in range(column_input + 1, len(columns)):
          print(i,j,matrix[i][j]))
```